# Swift, Firebase: No datas in realtime database after creating user

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using Xcode 10.1, Swift 4.2 and Firebase  ##

I can't see datas in my realtime database after uploading the datas to firebase with the following code:

```
static func createUser(username: String, email: String, password: String, imageData: Data, onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void, onError: @escaping (_ error: String?) -> Void) {

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (data, error) in
        if let err = error {
            onError(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        // User erfolgreich erstellt
        guard let uid = data?.user.uid else { return }
        self.uploadUserData(uid: uid, username: username, email: email, imageData: imageData, onSuccess: onSuccess)
    }
}

static func uploadUserData(uid: String, username: String, email: String, imageData: Data, onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void) {


    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_image").child(uid)

    storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
        if error != nil {
            return
        }
    }

    storageRef.downloadURL(completion:  { (url, error) in
        if  error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        let profilImageURL = url?.absoluteString


        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid)
        ref.setValue(["username" : username, "email" : email, "profileImageURL": profilImageURL ?? "Kein Bild vorhanden"])

    })
     onSuccess()
}
```

The settings in firebase:

[image: The settings in firebase]

Should work the right way. I already looked at the firebase documentation and didn't find more informations.

Comment: Are you sure the [user has write permission](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security) to `/users/$uid`?

Comment: sorry my mistake. edited the picture. read and write is on true.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. Please always post textual content as text. Pictures of text are not nearly as reusable, and searchable.

Comment: So you're saying your database remains empty after running this code?

Comment: yes after this code my realtime database is empty

Comment: If you simple call `ref.setValue(true)` instead, does that value get written to the database?

Comment: I insert `ref.setValue(true)´ but nothing was written to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the image get uploaded to Cloud Storage? If it does but the download URL isn't written to the database, my guess is it's because the data isn't uploaded before you generate the download URL. Since the upload function is asynchronous, the `downloadURL`function should be called from the closure.

```
static func uploadUserData(uid: String, username: String, email: String, imageData: Data, onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_image").child(uid)

    storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
        if error != nil {
            return
        }
        storageRef.downloadURL(completion:  { (url, error) in
        if  error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
     onSuccess()
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes the Picture get uploaded to the storage. But not the user data.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion then?

Comment: FIXED: I closed the bracket too early. Thank you very much for your help! :)